# iOS8 uitableview re-sizing incorrectly

Tags: uitableview, uiview, autolayout, ios8

I have a game where we offer videos for players to earn in game currency.  There is a new issue with iOS8 where the UITableViews in the game are incorrectly sized when the video is completed and the user is returned to the game screen.  It seems that whatever iOS8 is doing to support multiple screen sizes is buggy.

Any suggestions on how to force the screen to render the table views correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone happening across this question.  The problem turned out to be an issue within the AdColony SDK and its compatibility with iOS8.  They have released a new version that solved this issue.